# How to solve the Bhuman generate error using Cmake?

Tags: cmake, clang, clion

Yesterday, I downloaded the BhumanCodeRelease in https://github.com/bhuman/BHumanCodeRelease/tree/coderelease2022. But now, I follow the wiki https://wiki.b-human.de/coderelease2022/getting-started/#creating-project-files-compiling-the-code which I want to compile the code but failed.
**The environmenr is Ubuntu22.04.1 as the same the wiki asked.**
**Now I repeat my operation:**

```
$ sudo apt install ccache clang cmake git graphviz libasound2-dev libgl-dev libqt6opengl6-dev libqt6svg6-dev llvm mold net-tools ninja-build pigz qt6-base-dev rsync tk xterm xxd
$ cd BHumanCodeRelease/Make/Linux/
$ ./generate -c
```

- The wiki said, if you want to use Clion, you should RUN /Make/Linux/generate -c, I done but no useful, it can't generate Clion Cmake cache.
  [RUN generate -c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1xtN.png)
- Then I try to only use RUN /Make/Linux/generate, of course, it also generate nothing.
  [RUN generate without -c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnjnH.png)
- **I use Chrome to search the infomation, but no-one done it**.

I'm sure the environment follow the same and I didn't do anything extra.

- In fact, I guess the clang is the reason? But I'm not sure that, because of generate failed.
  [CMake in Clion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQbOe.png)
- But, I already download the clang and clang++ even the gcc
- Maybe the cmake verion or the code version?

Comment: [images of text are not appropriate here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541).

Comment: ok, I'll modify that